# Adding a Delimiter to a memo field in Access

Tags: vba, split

I am trying to delimit a memo field.  The field has within it multiple notes that I need to parse out into different columns.  Each note however follows the same logic, starts with mm/dd/yyyy then the note itself followed by a space.

So an example for one memo field would be

01/25/2000 worked on Rack-ID 03/03/2010 contracted Rack-ID 05/15/2014 updated Rack-ID

I need each note parsed out into a different column in Access.

I was working on the Split function in VBA, they had originally had "|" as a delimiter but removed it, now I have to pull on the dates

Note "tbl_example" is the table in my test access database
"Tx_example" is the name of the column holding the data to be delimited in my test access database

```
Sub Example()

On Error GoTo err_Handler

Dim rsD As DAO.Recordset
Set rsD = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("tbl_Example")

 Do While Not rsD.EOF
    rsD.Edit
    rsD!F1 = Trim(Split(rsD!Tx_Example, "|")(0))
    rsD!F2 = Trim(Split(rsD!Tx_Example, "|")(1))
    rsD!F3 = Trim(Split(rsD!Tx_Example, "|")(2))
    rsD.Update
    rsD.MoveNext
Loop


sub_Exit:

rsD.Close
Set rsD = Nothing
Exit Sub

err_Handler:

If Err.Number = 9 Then
    Resume Next
Else
    MsgBox "Err: " & Err.Number & vbNewLine & Err.Description
End If
End Sub
```

Not certain how I replace the "|" with a date search.
Also I'm not against doing a replace and inserting "|" right before each date so I would have my delimiter back.

Problem is I'm not sure how to find the date in a text memo field, otherwise I would be able to use the replace function, or an update query.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Public Function AddPipesBeforeDates(ByVal strText As String) As String
    Dim regex As RegExp
    Dim matches As Object

    Set regex = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    regex.Global = True
    regex.Pattern = "\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}"
    Set matches = regex.Execute(strText)
    For Each m In matches
        strText = Replace(strText, m, "|" & m)
    Next
    AddPipesBeforeDates = strText

    Set matches = Nothing
    Set regex = Nothing
End Function

Sub Example()

On Error GoTo err_Handler

Dim rsD As DAO.Recordset
Dim results as variant
Set rsD = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("tbl_Example")

 Do While Not rsD.EOF
    results = split(AddPipesBeforeDates(rsD!Tx_Example), "|")
    rsD.Edit
    rsD!F1 = Trim(results(1))
    rsD!F2 = Trim(results(2))
    rsD!F3 = Trim(results(3))
    rsD.Update
    rsD.MoveNext
Loop


sub_Exit:

rsD.Close
Set rsD = Nothing
Exit Sub

err_Handler:

If Err.Number = 9 Then
    Resume Next
Else
    MsgBox "Err: " & Err.Number & vbNewLine & Err.Description
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Diego, I will take a look at your code after I look over Dons, he was the first to reply.  Thank also for responding.

Comment: Good call moving the split out of the rs Edit and nice use of regex =o)

Comment: Hello Diego, thanks your code worked.  Apologies for the long delay, I got side tracked on something else.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote something like this recently to pull dated notes out of a memo field. This code may not work exactly as is, but will get you closer and give you some ideas.

**Some initial notes**: Don't expect the routine to do the full job on the first sweep. Create a temp table to write your results to, and each time you run the routine, clear the temp table first. After each run, tweak your code to catch everything it missed in the previous run. This way, you will refine the routine until you capture all your data accurately. You may also have to hand edit some notes to get them to work

```
+----------+------------+
|  Field   |  DataType  |
+----------+------------+
| NoteId   | AutoNumber |
| ParentId | Long       |
| NoteDate | Date/Time  |
| NoteNext | Memo       |
+----------+------------+
```

Also, I highly recommend not using multiple note fields in the same table. Your Notes table should look like my temp_Notes table above. After your routine is successful, its a simple matter of running against your Notes table rather than temp_Notes.

```
Public Sub MigrateNotes()

    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim rsDest As DAO.Recordset
    Dim rsSource As DAO.Recordset
    Dim nId As Long
    Dim aNotes() As String
    Dim n As Long
    Dim dtDate As Date
    Dim sNote As String

    On Error GoTo EH

    DoCmd.Hourglass True

    Set db = CurrentDb

    db.Execute "DELETE * FROM temp_Notes"

    Set rsDest = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM temp_Notes")
    Set rsSource = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT RowId,Diary FROM SourceNotes")

    With rsSource
        Do Until .EOF
            nId = .Fields("RowId").Value

            aNotes = parseNotes(.Fields("Diary").Value)
            For n = 0 To UBound(aNotes)

                dtDate = CDate(Left(aNotes(n), 10))
                sNote = Right(aNotes(n), Len(aNotes(n)) - 11)

                With rsDest
                    .AddNew
                    .Fields("RowId").Value = nId
                    .Fields("NoteDate").Value = dtDate
                    .Fields("NoteText").Value = sNote
                    .Update
                End With

            Next 'n

            .MoveNext
        Loop
    End With

    MsgBox "Complete"

    GoTo FINISH

EH:

    With Err
        MsgBox .Number & vbCrLf & .Source & vbCrLf & .Description
        .Clear
    End With

    'for debugging purposes
    Debug.Assert 0
    GoTo FINISH
    Resume

FINISH:
    DoCmd.Hourglass False

    On Error Resume Next
    'release resources

    If Not rsDest Is Nothing Then
        rsDest.Close
        Set rsDest = Nothing
    End If

    If Not rsSource Is Nothing Then
        rsSource.Close
        Set rsSource = Nothing
    End If

End Sub

Private Function parseNotes(ByVal sRaw As String) As String()

    Dim nYear As Long
    Dim sYearToken As String
    Dim nIndex As Long
    Dim nSkip As Long

    For nYear = 1999 To Year(Date)

        sYearToken = "/" & nYear & " "

        'use 12 to skip past first date ("mm/dd/yyyy " = 11)
        nSkip = 12

        Do
            'find the end of the date
            nIndex = InStr(nSkip, sRaw, sYearToken)

            If nIndex > 0 Then

                'find the start of the date
                nIndex = nIndex - 6

                sRaw = Left(sRaw, nIndex) & vbCrLf & Right(sRaw, Len(sRaw) - nIndex)

                'use 12 to skip past next date
                nSkip = nIndex + 12

            End If

        Loop Until nIndex <= 0

    Next 'n

    parseNotes = Split(sRaw, vbCrLf)

End Function
```

Comment: wow thanks Don, Sorry for the late reply I've been working on somthing else.  Again thanks for the time put into this, I will need some time to go through and understand the code, your comments are very appreciated and helpful, still a novice at all this.  Again thanks.